# What do you do during Brahma muhurta? What is your sadhana like?

Tags: mantras

Could anyone please share what their sadhana is like during Brahma muhurta? What rituals and mantras do you chant and in what order? Do you do achamanam and pranayama? Chant mantras or sing bhajans? Meditate?

Comment: if your question is about others Sadhana, then it will be personal opinion based and we don't encourage these questions.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Why not? Hinduism is a living, practiced based tradition. We are not a people of a book. I am a Hindu who is not from India and I would like to learn about the daily practices and rituals of other Hindus.

Comment: @MahaRex The site does not allow any sort of ''primarily opinion-based'' or ''personal'' questions. Its nothing to do with Hinduism being a ''living, practice based religion'' and not being ''people of a book''.

Comment: Wonder why the question has been closed as personal opinion based? These practices are not limited to just one single person, in fact anyone can follow them but for that we need to understand the correct rituals, no?

Comment: @Just_Do_It It is closed because it is asking user's opinions. Such questions are not allowed for all SE sites because there's no correct answer and infinite answers are possible.  Read [help/dont-ask]

Comment: @Sarvabhouma but you can always modify the question, no?

Comment: @Just_Do_It No. not for these kinds. OP is already informed what will happen and theuy didn't do it. OP's ointent is the most important. Only OP's intent should be taken into consideration while doing such edits which change meaning completely. So, it can't be edited and reopened. We should close questions too. It's not bad.

Comment: @Viper91 You could modify your question like what prayers and other chants, etc are prescribed in scriptures for Bramha Mahurata (early morning). It will then be non-opinion based question as you are specifically asking from scriptures. If you ask people about what they do then there might be hundreds of answers out of which you yourself will be confused about which one to follow. So that's why this site restricts opinion based answers. Hope you understand this.

Answer (score 5):

What Sadhana one should perform at Brahma-Muhurta is described in [**Garuda Purana**](http://archive.indianscriptures.com/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/garud-puran/garuda-vol-2/chapter-01/topic-23)  -Chapter 50 -Verse 1 - Discourses on charities and gift-makings, etc.- See page No. 113 .

> ।।ब्रह्मोवाच ।। 
>  अहन्यहनि यः कुर्य्यात्क्रियां स ज्ञानमाप्नुयात्
>   ।।
>   **ब्राह्मे मुहूर्त्ते** चोत्थाय धर्ममर्थं च चिन्तयेत् ।। Garuda Purana 50.1 ।।
>
> Brahma Said : He who performs religious rites daily attains to Jnāna
>   (knowledge). Having got up from bed at the **Brahma-muhurta** he
>   should meditate on religious profit and worldly profit.

---

Now the next two verses gives us the idea what to do after waking up in Brahma-Muhurta. Its sid that a person should meditate and after that after completing necessary rites (daily routines related to body)  , he should go to river for ritual bathing .And he should perform purification rites at the river i.e. Sandhya-Vandanam

> चिन्तयेद्धृदि पद्मस्थमानन्दमजरं हरिम् ।।
>  उषः काले तु संप्राप्ते
>   कृत्वा चावश्यकं बुधः ।। Garuda Purana 50.2 ।।
>  स्त्रायान्नदीषु शुद्धासु शौचं
>   कृत्वा यथाविधि ।।
>  प्रतः स्नानेन पूर्यते येऽपि पापकृतो जनाः ।। Garuda Purana  50.3
>   ।।
>
> He should also meditate, in the lotus of his heart, on blissful and
>   undecaying Hari. When the dawn approaches a learned man, having
>   performed the necessary rites, should repair to a river of pure water
>   for bathing, and perform there duly the purificatory rite. Even sinful
>   wights are sanctified by morning ablutions.

---

It is said in Garuda Purana that one should perform Achamana or libations of water to the sun .With **Gayatri Mantra** .

> आचम्य विधिवन्नित्यं पुनराचम्य वाग्यतः ।।
>  संमार्ज्य मन्त्रै
>   रात्मानं कुशैः सोदकबिन्दुभिः ।। 50.16||
>  आपोहिष्ठाव्याहृतिभिः
>   सावित्र्या वारुणैः शुभैः ।।
>  ॐकारव्याहृतियुतां गायत्त्रीं वेदमातरम्
>   ।। 50.17 ।।
>
> Having rinsed his mouth he should do it again observing silence.
>   Having sprinkled his body with drops of water through Kuśa reeds and
>   with Mantrams, Apohistha, Vyarhriti and the auspicious Vāruni and
>   having recited the Gayatri, consisting of Om and Vyarhriti, the mother
>   of the Vedas, he should offer libations of water to the sun with his
>   mind fixed in him.

---

So yes one can perform sadhana like  Achamana , Pranayama , meditation , chanting of mantras , study of the vedas etc. at Brahma Muhurtha. Which we can read as described in that chapter.

We can also read this chapter from [**Wisdom Library site**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt/d/doc122530.html)

---

<sub>Instead of personal practice i am herewith providing more general answer from scriptures.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to find someone to learn these rituals properly.

Comment: Why not sandhyA vandanam ?